# JS Дождаться выполнения воспроизведения звука

Tags: javascript

Необходимо дождаться воспроизведения уведомления и после этого выполнить некоторые действия. Как отловить неудачное воспроизведение мне известно:

```
var notifications = new Audio('/template/sounds/notifications/3.mp3');

notifications.play().catch((error) => {
            
  console.log('do');
                 
});
```

А как отловить удачное? Не `catch`, а `try`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор [Audio()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) создаёт и возвращает новый HTMLAudioElement, который наследует свойства [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). Для решения вашей задачи, нужно добавить обработку события `ended` [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event)

```js
var notifications = new Audio('/template/sounds/notifications/3.mp3');
notifications.addEventListener('ended', () => console.log('stop'));
notifications.play();
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручили